# Can anyone tell me why tableview data are not displaying until scroll?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

In my tableview i have set xml data to display but until scroll it does not display all value. I have reloaded the tableview when i am getting my xml data. I also used `[cell.contenView viewWithTag:tagnumber];` But still now its not Working...please help me anybody....

**Data are coming and using `NSLog` i can get the value but not display until scroll.** 
**One think i have to mention that i can see the my cellview and imageview but not showing lable data.**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

          // THIS IS A VIEW ABOVE MY CELL NAME: cellView    

    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,290, 120)] autorelease];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order_description_bg.png"]];
    cellView.tag =10;

         // THIS IS A IMAGEVIEW ABOVE MY cellView NAME: imgView

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 39, 36)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_image.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    imgView.tag = 5;

           // THIS IS A LABEL ABOVE MY cellView NAME: statusLabel

            CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
    statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    statusLabel.tag = 1;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

}


  //  [cell.contentView superview];
cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];

if(searching == YES && x<=inumOfRowAfterSearch){
        NSLog(@"[[searchData objectAtIndex:m] intValue] is : %d",[[searchData objectAtIndex:inumOfRowAfterSearch] intValue]);
            y = [[searchData objectAtIndex:inumOfRowAfterSearch] intValue];

    cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
    statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];

    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO && x<=inumOfRowAfterSearch){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
     }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO && x<=inumOfRowAfterSearch){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
}
else{

    cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
    statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];

    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO){
      statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSLog(@"status lable value: %@",statusLabel.text);
        }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
}
return cell;
}
```

**Before scroll the table.**

[image]

**After Scroll the tableview**

[image]

Comment: did you add delegate to your tableview?.

Comment: try adding these lines at the end of the cellforrowatIndexPath method:    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

Comment: yes i have added delegate and i have tried according to your second comment. but still not working...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following codes are not necessary in each condition , since you have written the code outside of the condition. It seems duplicate.

```
cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
```

And coming to your question, it seems initially it skips both `if` and `else if` conditions. Comment also the `NSLog`s and write `NSLog` in `else` part of the conditions.

**Edit:**

```
//  [cell.contentView superview];
cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];

if(searching == YES && x<=inumOfRowAfterSearch){
    NSLog(@"[[searchData objectAtIndex:m] intValue] is : %d",[[searchData objectAtIndex:inumOfRowAfterSearch] intValue]);
    y = [[searchData objectAtIndex:inumOfRowAfterSearch] intValue];

    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO ){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO ){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    else
    {
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: None"];
    }
}
else{
    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSLog(@"status lable value: %@",statusLabel.text);
    }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO){
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    else
    {
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: None"];
    }
}
return cell;
```

Comment: After your edit code i tried it but still now its not working....thanks for your quick..please give me any other solution.

Comment: will i post my `viewdidload` and `viewwillappear`?? where i am reloading my tableview???

Comment: I just wanted you to check whether the label values are set properly. Us e my edited code, and let me know what value is set to the label

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *statusLabel; in .h file and synthesize statusLabel; in .m file

Comment: I didn't ask about the property. Did you use my code? By default, you would now get a value in the label.. What it is showing?

Comment: using your code i can get the first section's lable value only....after scrolling i can see the other values of label on the other sections..like my image...thats mean no change

Comment: I have solved my problem..actually it was not any scroll problem it happened for the size of my cellview image...whatever it is thanks for your help and patients.